# Insert spaces to characters without replacement in R

Tags: r, character

I have a character vector as follows:

```
x = c("word", "another", "final", "more")
```

I would like to include spaces before and/or after each word.

```
y = c(" word ", " another ", " final ", " more ")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean `x = c("word", "another", "final", "more")`?

Comment: I believe so. The original text was a full character string, "Word another final more." That was then cut down using the "tokenizers" package to create what I entered as "x" above.

Comment: `paste0(" ", x, " ")`

Comment: And if someone ends up here wanting the reverse - see `?trimws`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution by HubertL:

```
y <- paste0(" ", x, " ")
```

Nicer solution:

```
y <- paste("", x, "")
```

This is assuming you want spaces in either sides of every word.

Answer (score 1):

Or (for completeness):

```
sprintf(" %s ", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with a regular expression

```
gsub("^", " ", gsub("$", " ", x))
```